# FadeOut this jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

Best,

How can I fade out this, if it ends? It not always show content, only if the person got a message. I googled it, and i couldn't find it.

This code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("<?php echo $host_url; ?>/system/globalmsg.php", function (result) {
                $('#globms').hide().html(result).fadeIn(800);
            })
        }, 5000);
    })
</script>
```

Thanks! ;)

Comment: Now what is your problem? provide  jsfiddle link

Comment: I want to fade this out after 5000 ms.

Comment: OK but now only fadeOut problem is there ,everything is ok ,correct?

Comment: How come i know "if the person got a message" ? Is it stored in "result" ? If yes ,what value can be there of "result" parameter?

Comment: The content shows a notification, but after that 5000ms i want to fade out it, like i fade it in. 

Normal i never code in jQuery,

Comment: If you want to fade out the message use fadeOut(800) instead of fadeIn.

Comment: so fade in is ok with it ,you want =>"fadeout" also Which is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("<?php echo $host_url; ?>/system/globalmsg.php", function (result) {
                $('#globms').hide().html(result).fadeIn(800).fadeOut(500);
            })
        }, 5000);
    })
</script>
```

You can change fadeOut parameter value as you want.

Comment: Thanks! This code works for me:

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get("<?php echo $host_url; ?>/system/globalmsg.php", function (result) {
                $('#globms').hide().html(result).fadeIn(800).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
            })
        }, 6000);
    })
</script>

Comment: please do some contribution to answer which are helpful and solve your Question